# Catastrophic failure in constructor of XMLValidatingReader

Tags: c#, xml

I am developing a library (VS 2010, assembly targeted for AnyCPU) and I am getting the following error while stepping over the constructor of `XmlValidationReader(..)`. The parameter for this constructor is an instance of `XmlReader()`, and the specific XML is syntactically correct, and validates with third party tool.

> Error: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF
>   (E_UNEXPECTED))
>
> Exception object: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>
> Stack trace:
>
> System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle
>   peFile, SecurityZone& zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)    at
>   System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()
>   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type
>   evidenceType)    at
>   System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type
>   evidenceType)    at
>   System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)    at
>   System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean
>   markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)    at
>   System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type
>   evidenceType)    at
>   System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)    at
>   System.Security.Policy.Evidence.RawEvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Security.Policy.Evidence.EvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain
>   appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain
>   appDomain, String exePath)    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean
>   includeUserConfig)    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath,
>   Boolean includeUserConfig)    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord
>   record)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String
>   configKey)    at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    at
>   System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaCollection..ctor(XmlNameTable nametable)
>   at System.Xml.XmlValidatingReaderImpl..ctor(XmlReader reader)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlValidatingReader..ctor(XmlReader reader)

I have not changed any security configuration in the system. The specific account under which the assembly is loaded has administrative privileges. Any idea of what could cause this issue? I have run through the web extensively, but in vain.

Comment: Thats a lot of error code to debug without us having insight into the code.

Comment: public bool Validate(string xmlSource)
{
    XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlSource));
    return validate(reader);
}

private bool validate(XmlReader reader)
{
    try
    {
        XmlValidatingReader validator = new XmlValidatingReader(reader);

Comment: @toxicate20. It seems to be sporadic occurrence and tied up with profile corruption.

Comment: The fact that it's an InterOpServices ComException points away from your  immediatel, code which does not appear to contain anything Com-ish.  Do you have any idea why you are getting ComExceptions?